Dapper using the incorrect culture when converting DateTime DB type to string from result set
We've been using an older version of Dapper for quite a while now on our .net web application without any issues. We've recently upgraded Dapper to the latest version and noticed that Dapper does not use the current culture of the web application when converting a DB DateTime type to a string property in the model from the result set. There's no problem when the property in the model is of DateTime. There's only the issue when the property is a string that Dapper needs to convert to from the DB DateTime value. I'm not sure if this is configuration issue in the web application or if Dapper changed the way it converts DateTime values to strings. Is there a way for me to specify what culture Dapper needs to use, on a global level, when it does these conversions? We need the format of the date string to be en-GB but the format that Dapper is converting to is en-US.
Our current web application has the culture set as <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />

Pretty sure Dapper is using invariant rules for all conversions and has for a very long time; if that doesn't suit: I'd suggest loading the values as string and parsing them manually

Dapper doesn't do conversion of dates. They come from the server as binary, then get converted to a DateTime or DateTimeOffset. It's your application which is stringifying them incorrectly. Either that, or it was stored in the database incorrectly.

AFAIK Dapper is just an orm for RDMBS ! Nothing to do with database ot its language ... Checking connection string and specifying culture may help in some situations, etc.
